# Console main Input

Tags: c++, input, console

Okay Some may remember me from earlier, I am fairly new to programming so I may seem not up to par with many others. However at the moment, i am very much stuck.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string temp,input,output;//store input from file, and get which file//

    ofstream out("output.txt");

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        if(ifstream(argv[2]))
        {
            input = argv[2];
            ifstream in(input);
            while(in.good())
            {
                in >> temp;
                ReverseWord(temp);
                cout << temp << endl;
                out << temp << endl;
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }

}
```

This code right here is meant to reverse the letter order of words that it takes in from a file by typing "revstr < input.txt" with input.txt being the file name. however at the moment the program just opens and closes right away without anything happening and nothing being typed into the console. does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: On Windows? `system("pause");`...

Comment: `<` is special in shells (including `cmd.exe`): it redirects input from file to your `stdin` (or `std::cin`), and *the program doesn't see* neither `<` nor the file name.

Comment: Or better yet, `cin.ignore()` and `cin.get()`.

Comment: @chris Where would I place those in the code?

Comment: @MagicalToast, At the end, so it stays open after everything's finished. Alternatively, run the console program how it was meant to be run: through the command line.

Comment: Why would `argc` be 3? What are the arguments?

Comment: Oh, and `main` is an int function, that is, it returns an integer. What is the value it returns?

Comment: @MrLister, In the code shown, 0.

Comment: @christ I was asking the OP about his/her understanding of C functions.

Comment: @MrLister The arguments to be typed in are "revstr < input.txt" no quotes of course however my issue now is that after I type those in, the file just closes now after putting the `cin.get()` and the `cin.ignore()` at the beginning after the declarations of strings. also it returns 0 if it was successful and returns 1 if not.

Comment: @MagicalToast in that case, `argc` will be 1, and the program won't do anything, because the program only works if `argc` is 3! It won't even close the output file. (Well, it will eventually, but not explicitly.)

Comment: @MrLister I don't think I understand what you are saying, does the console think that the entire line is the argument?

Comment: No; as Anton said above, the program won't see the name of the input file if you type `revstr < input.txt` on the command line. It will only see its own name, `revstr`, which will be the first and only arg.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your program as `revstr < input.text` your `main()` function will be called (on usual platforms) with:

```
argv = { "revstr", NULL }
argc = 1
```

In this case you get the contents of `input.txt` by reading from std::cin. That is what 'input readirection' means: your standard input stream is redirected to read from a file rather than the keyboard (aka terminal) device. No need to deal with the filename in that case.

To pass a filename as argument, use `revstr input.txt`. That should call `main()`with

```
argv = { "revstr", "input.txt", NULL }
argc = 2
```

so the filename will be available as `argv[1]`.

The behavior in the former case is typically due to command shells, which treat '<' as a redirection directive (which ends the preceding command). You may have expected to get

```
argv = { "revstr", "<", "input.txt", NULL }
argc = 3
```

For that you would need to apply some form of quoting or escaping to disable the shell behavior, for example `revstr "<" input.txt`or `revstr \< input.txt`. But as far as I understand where you are coming from, you want the redirection. In that case forget about argc and argv and simply read your input from `std::cin`.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I want the console to read "revstr < input.txt" and that alone and if the "input.txt" is an existing file, to take it's contest and reverse the order of the strings in it.

Comment: Then you don't need to deal with arguments in main(). Instead read the strings to reverse directly from cin.

Comment: string temp,input,output, argv[3];//store input from file, and get which file//
 int argc = 0, i = 0;
 ofstream out("output.txt");
 if(argc == 3)

Comment: Would the cin go into an array of strings?

Comment: std::cin is the standard input stream. You read from it, like you read from `in` in your code. Use `cin >> string_to_reverse` for whitespace-separated strings. Use `getline(cin, string_to_reverse)` to read entire lines.

Comment: the problem with me is that I have a lack of visualization from text. I Know what your talking about but I just can't wrap my head on where to make edits and changes. I took out the arguments in the main function but have no clue where to put the cin or if I even need a counter to check how many arguments or anything.

Comment: From the code you posted, keep only the while loop inside main and replace `in` with `cin`. You only need the `temp` string declared and you don't need any of the `if` statements. (There may be other issues with the loop, but that would be another question.)